# Is there way to display content of textbox only upto textbox size is ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics

SSRS report
I have to print customer address in a report by making it's content visible only upto textbox size and in a single line since I am printing the report in pre printed paper with one blank line for address.

I tried setting canGrow property to false,but it doesnot work.Any ideas?

Comment: Setting the can grow property should do it. Is the textbox part of a tablix/matrix or is it just a plain text box? I just did a quick test and setting the cangrow property to false truncated the text as expected.

Comment: @alan thank you for reply.Adjusting the size of the textbox to display only a single line worked .seems like size of textbox was little big.